# jQuery drop down menu item to go back up when not hovering on it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have managed to get my menu items to drop down on hover but once they are down, they stay down. How can I get it to go back to hidden when I am not hovering on the item?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".downservices").hover(function(){
        $(".servicesdropped").slideDown("fast");
        
        
        
    });
});
</script>
```

The Menu:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/buy-ads">Buy Ads</a></li>
        <li class="downservices"><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
    <div class="servicesdropped">
    <ul class="middle">
    
        <li><a href="#">Arts & Entertainment</a></li>                                          
<li><a href="#">Automotive</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Business &amp; Services</a></li>                                  
<li><a href="#">Community & Social</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Construction & Contractors</a></li>                                 
<li><a href="#">Designing</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>                        
<li><a href="#">Education</a></li>   
<li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>                                                 
<li><a href="#">Food & Dining</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Government & legal</a></li>                                               
  
        
        
    </ul>
    <ul class="middle">
    <li><a href="#">Health & Fitness</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Home & Garden</a></li>                                                
<li><a href="#">Industry & Agriculture</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Media & Communications</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Medical & Medicine</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Personal Care & Services</a></li>                                      
<li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>                              
<li><a href="#">Sports & Recreation Activities</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>   




                            
    </ul>
    
    </div>
    
    <li class="downservices2"><a href="#">Quick Links</a></li>
    <div class="servicesdropped2">
    
    <ul class="middle">
    <li><a href="#">Attorneys defense</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Banks</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Broadcasting</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Charity & networking</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Clubs</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Corporate</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cosmetics</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Educational services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Home & building services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Imports and exports</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    
    <ul class="middle">
    <li><a href="#">Improvement & supplies</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Investments and rentals</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Life style design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Manufacture & dealers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Name Brands</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Physicians & medical centers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Restaurants</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sports clubs</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tv's & computers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Vacation</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    </div>

        <li><a href="/faq">Faq</a></li>
        
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hover can accept two handler functions, one for `mouseenter`, and one for `mouseleave` Just add the `handlerOut` function like so,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aUPV2/)**

```
$(".downservices").hover(
        function(){$(".servicesdropped").slideDown("fast");},
        function(){$(".servicesdropped").slideUp("fast");}
);
```

**Updated** When sub items are not direct children.

**[Live Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/aUPV2/4/)**

```
$(".servicesdropped").bind('mouseleave', function(){$(this).slideUp("fast");});

$(".downservices").mouseover(
        function(){$(".servicesdropped").slideDown("fast");}
);
```

**[Hover Reference](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**

Comment: So simple! Thanks for the help and the links. I think I'm really going to like jQuery.

Comment: Oh wait, so now it goes back up but when I am hovering over the content that is in the drop down it doesn't stay dropped down.

Comment: @user605530 Ah Im guessing the content is not a child of the element you are hovering over?

Comment: @user605530 check out the updated code, it should work for you.

Comment: i added the menu to my original post, check my edit, it's still bouncing around all crazy, hmmm

Comment: ok @user605530 give it another try.. hopefully works fully this time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish the [signature](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) `hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )` Put a function for `.slideUp()` in the `handerOut()`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".downservices").hover(
        function(){ $(".servicesdropped").slideDown("fast");}
        function(){ $(".servicesdropped").slideUp("fast");}
    );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".downservices").toggle(function(){
        $(".servicesdropped").slideDown("fast");
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".downservices").hover(function(){
        $(".servicesdropped").slideDown("fast");
    }, function(){
        $(".servicesdropped").slideUp("fast"););
});
```

May be [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)  can helps u too :)

Answer (score 0):

Hover has both an in, and out callback. Give this a try

```
$(".downservices").hover(
    function(){ $(".servicesdropped").slideDown("fast"); },
    function(){ $(".servicesdropped").slideUp("fast"); },
});
```